# How do I force a browser to go to my local site in IIS instead of the internet site?

Tags: iis, localhost

I have a handful of sites set up in the root directory of IIS.  I also have them set up in the host file, to route to my local IP address.  When I open a browser and type 127.0.0.1/example/index.html, the page opens in my browser. I need to be able to type in example.com and have it open that page, but when I type example.com in a browser, I get the following:

Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to example.com.

- The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a
  few moments.
- If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network
  connection.
- If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make
  sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Also, it changes in the address line of the browser to https://example.com. What could be preventing it from opening my local site?

Comment: This is a question more related to DNS and has been asked a million times. If you don't want to use a local DNS server to control the resolution of `example.com`, you might modify `hosts` file, https://www.whatsmydns.net/hosts-file.html

Comment: I already tried modifying the hosts file, as stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently it is an issue with the Firefox browser.  I tried in both Edge (ew) and Chrome, and the local site came up as expected.  I tried making a couple of network security changes in Firefox, but was not able to get it to work, so I'm just going to use Chrome.

Comment: To me issue with firefox was that I first opened real page and firefox saved it  in history, so it would load it even if you specify to force local page load in `/etc/hosts`. But after deleting browser history, it starts loading local page instead.